# Rounded Value Not Correctly Inserting into Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database in which there is some data dumped into an Excel workbook via vba code.  Some of the values have a lengthy decimal which I want to round to the nearest tenth.  I don't want the value rounded to the tenth if it is a whole number (i.e., I don't want 45 rounded to 45.0), so I'm using the following code:

```
If Fix(rstTmpRegularAndOvertimeHours!regularhours) = rstTmpRegularAndOvertimeHours!regularhours Then
      objWS.cells(intRowCount, 6).Value = rstTmpRegularAndOvertimeHours!regularhours
    Else
      objWS.cells(intRowCount, 6).Value = Round(rstTmpRegularAndOvertimeHours!regularhours, 1)
    End If
```

The rounded value is displayed in the cell, however, the actual value entered is the unrounded value.  For example, the value is 4.19999980926513, and when this code is run, the value 4.2 is displayed in the cell, but if you click on the cell you see that the actual value is still 4.19999980926513.  And when the following line of code runs:

```
With objWS.PageSetup
    .Orientation = 2
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
```

The cell expands to show the whole value and shows 4.19999980926513 again.  I am using similar code in other places and am getting the correct rounded value inserted into the spreadsheet.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what `FIX()` is doing but it must be the problem because your round code looks right.  This means you are not falling into the `ELSE`.

Comment: @Steve  The `FIX()` simply truncates any decimal, so if `FIX([number])=[number]` that means there's no decimal so I don't need to round (thus preventing 45 from turning into 45.0).  I've used this same logic elsewhere in my code and have no problem getting it to round the values and insert the rounded value into the cell.  I have stepped through the code and it is indeed falling into the `ELSE` - in fact if I insert `MsgBox(Round(rstTmpRegularAndOvertimeHours!regularhours, 1))`, it gives me 4.2, but that is not the value inserted into Excel.  Somehow the rounded value is not carrying over.

Answer (score 3):

Decimal fractions are challenging for binary systems.

`Round()` returns a double precision float.  But 4.2 can not be stored *exactly* as a double.  So instead the double value is an *approximation* of 4.2, and it's the closest you can get with a double.

So what what you're seeing in Excel is that actual double value.  If you want to display it with a single decimal place --- and then adjust the column width based on that --- change the Excel column format to "Number" with 1 for the "decimal places" property.

Comment: Thanks - this works.  I still don't totally understand why this works sometimes and doesn't others, but changing the format of that cell works.  (Don't want to change the format for the entire column because I don't want to get 45.0 like I described before).  Thanks!